# Friction forces in an idealized model of hydroplaning

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, friction, free-body-diagram

I am reading this question from this [text](https://books.google.com.sa/books/about/Fluid_Mechanics.html?id=d9B5NElxUKwC&redir_esc=y)

[image]

I am not sure how to write the friction force in terms of the contact area $A$, speed $u$, mass $M$, viscosity $\mu$ and thickness $h$. The friction force as I understand is defined

$$F_{f} = \mu_f F_{N}$$

where $\mu_f$ is the coefficient of friction and $F_{N}$ is the normal force. How do I incorporate the other variables into the friction force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the idea is to consider that the water film is experiencing Couette flow, with boundary constraints such that the flow speed is $u$ at the point of contact with the tire and $0$ on the point of contact with the road.

Assuming Couette flow, the speed $v(y)$ as a function of height $y$ is:
$$v(y) = u\frac{y}{h}$$

In such a flow, the shear stress is constant everywhere; which we can assume is the source of friction for the car. This shear stress is
$$\tau = \mu \frac{dv}{dy} = \mu \frac{u}{h}$$
This shear stress acts everywhere on the surface of the contact area, so multiplying by the contact area gives us the effective friction force:
$$ F = A \tau = \mu A \frac{u}{h}$$
Notice that the mass plays no role! This is because of the Couette assumption; the only thing driving/affecting the flow here is the fact that the tires are moving at speed $u$, and the pressure developed by the car pushing downwards on the water film isn't considered.